# Check Spinner for Selection before setting Position

Tags: java, android, spinner

I was wondering if it was possible to check that a spinner contains a Value/Selection before setting the position to that value/Selection. What I am doing is that a customer has options for a product EX: RED, YELLOW, GREEN. When they make the selection is it recorded in my DB. When the customer loads that Item to edit I need to set the spinner position to that selection. I can do this with no problems. The problem is that if they log back in and their cart repopulates after a week, an option may no longer be available so I need to make sure that it is still available before the selection. I have tried checking the ArrayList which is what I think I need to do but I am not entirely sure. I did try but it crashes the app. Any Ideas? Thanks in advance. Below is my code.

LOADING THE SELECTED OPTIONS:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerOpt1;
     ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerOpt2;
     ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerOpt3;


class LoadSelectedOptions extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.d("CONFIRM SPIN STAT 1::", Integer.toString(SpinStat1));

            if(SpinStat1==1){
                Log.d("SPINSTAT1", Integer.toString(SpinStat1));
                List<NameValuePair> Options = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                Options.add(new BasicNameValuePair(DO_FUNCTION, SEL_OPT_FUNCTION1));
                Options.add(new BasicNameValuePair(SEL_ITEM_COUNT, theProduct_Number));

                JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(master_url, "GET", Options);
                Log.d("SPINSTAT1", json.toString());
                try{
                    sel_success1  = json.getInt(SEL_SUCCESS1);
                     JSONArray selected_1 = json.getJSONArray(OPT_CATAGORIES);

                     if (sel_success1 == 1) {
                         for (int i = 0; i < selected_1.length(); i++) {
                             JSONObject c = selected_1.getJSONObject(i);
                             sel_opt1 = c.getString(SEL_OPT1);
                         }
                    }else {

                    }
                }catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                    }

            if(SpinStat2==1){
                List<NameValuePair> Options2 = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                Options2.add(new BasicNameValuePair(DO_FUNCTION, SEL_OPT_FUNCTION2));
                Options2.add(new BasicNameValuePair(SEL_ITEM_COUNT, theProduct_Number));

                JSONObject json2 = jParser.makeHttpRequest(master_url, "GET", Options2);

                try{
                    sel_success2  = json2.getInt(SEL_SUCCESS2);
                     JSONArray selected_2 = json2.getJSONArray(OPT_CATAGORIES);

                     if (sel_success2 == 1) {
                         for (int i = 0; i < selected_2.length(); i++) {
                             JSONObject c = selected_2.getJSONObject(i);
                             sel_opt2 = c.getString(SEL_OPT2);
                         }
                    }else {

                    }
                }catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            if(SpinStat3==1){
                List<NameValuePair> Options3 = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                Options3.add(new BasicNameValuePair(DO_FUNCTION, SEL_OPT_FUNCTION3));
                Options3.add(new BasicNameValuePair(SEL_ITEM_COUNT, theProduct_Number));

                JSONObject json3 = jParser.makeHttpRequest(master_url, "GET", Options3);

                try{
                    sel_success3  = json3.getInt(SEL_SUCCESS3);
                     JSONArray selected_3 = json3.getJSONArray(OPT_CATAGORIES);

                     if (sel_success3 == 1) {
                         for (int i = 0; i < selected_3.length(); i++) {
                             JSONObject c = selected_3.getJSONObject(i);
                             sel_opt3 = c.getString(SEL_OPT3);
                         }
                    }else {

                    }
                }catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            return null;
        }
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                    //SpinStat is a value determining if there are options. 0==No Options   1==Options Are Available
                    if(SpinStat1==1){
//spinnerOpt1 is the ArrayAdapter for that specific spinner. It is loaded from a List/ArrayList "options1"
                    }else if(spinnerOpt1.equals(sel_opt1)){
                        Spinner1.setSelection(spinnerOpt1.getPosition(sel_opt1));
                    }

                    if(SpinStat2==1){
                    }else if(spinnerOpt2.equals(sel_opt2)){
                        Spinner2.setSelection(spinnerOpt2.getPosition(sel_opt2));
                    }

                    if(SpinStat3==1){
                    }else if(spinnerOpt3.equals(sel_opt3)){
                        Spinner3.setSelection(spinnerOpt3.getPosition(sel_opt3));
                    }

                }

            });
        }
    }
```

LOGCAT::

```
07-16 13:41:49.875: E/AndroidRuntime(20378): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-16 13:41:49.875: E/AndroidRuntime(20378): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-16 13:41:49.875: E/AndroidRuntime(20378):    at com.example.shopper.EditCart$LoadSelectedOptions$1.run(EditCart.java:689)
07-16 13:41:49.875: E/AndroidRuntime(20378):    at android.app.Activity.runOnUiThread(Activity.java:4784)
07-16 13:41:49.875: E/AndroidRuntime(20378):    at com.example.shopper.EditCart$LoadSelectedOptions.onPostExecute(EditCart.java:675)
07-16 13:41:49.875: E/AndroidRuntime(20378):    at com.example.shopper.EditCart$LoadSelectedOptions.onPostExecute(EditCart.java:1)
07-16 13:41:49.875: E/AndroidRuntime(20378):    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
07-16 13:41:49.875: E/AndroidRuntime(20378):    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
07-16 13:41:49.875: E/AndroidRuntime(20378):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
07-16 13:41:49.875: E/AndroidRuntime(20378):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-16 13:41:49.875: E/AndroidRuntime(20378):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-16 13:41:49.875: E/AndroidRuntime(20378):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
07-16 13:41:49.875: E/AndroidRuntime(20378):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-16 13:41:49.875: E/AndroidRuntime(20378):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-16 13:41:49.875: E/AndroidRuntime(20378):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1008)
07-16 13:41:49.875: E/AndroidRuntime(20378):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:775)
07-16 13:41:49.875: E/AndroidRuntime(20378):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

LOADING OPTIONS TO SPINNER::

```
class LoadOptions1 extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        /**
         * getting All products from url
         * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
    try {
        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
     params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(DO_FUNCTION, OPT_FUNCTION));
     params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("PROD_ID", GET_PID));
        // getting JSON string from URL
     Log.d("PROD_ID", GET_PID);
        Log.d("DO_FUNCTION", OPT_FUNCTION);
        Log.d("master_url", master_url);
        JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(master_url, "GET", params);

        // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
        Log.d("All Options: ", json.toString());

        // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
        success2  = json.getInt(OPT_SUCCESS);
        Log.d("success2", Integer.toString(success2));
        if (success2 == 1) {
            // products found
            // Getting Array of Products
            JSONArray catagories = json.getJSONArray(OPT_CATAGORIES);

            // looping through All Products
            for (int i = 0; i < catagories.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject c = catagories.getJSONObject(i);

                // Storing each json item in variable
                String category = c.getString(OPT_CATAGORY);

                options1.add(category);


            }

        } else {
            // no products found
            // Launch Add New product Activity

        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
    }
    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
        if (!(success2 == 0)) {
            SpinStat1 = 1;
            Log.d("SET SPIN STAT 1::", Integer.toString(SpinStat1));
            spinnerOpt1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(EditCart.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, options1);
                Spinner1.setAdapter(spinnerOpt1);
               // MySpinner.setSelection(spinnerMenu.getPosition("Select A Catagory"));

        }else{
            textView8.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            Spinner1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            SpinStat1 = 0;
        }


    }

    }
```

THE ANSWER:: Check the value against the list.

```
if(SpinStat1==1){
                    }else if(options1.contains(sel_opt1)){
                        Spinner1.setSelection(spinnerOpt1.getPosition(sel_opt1));
                    }
```

Comment: Post your logcat. Also, you don't need `runOnUiThread()` because `onPostExecute()` already runs on the `UI`

Comment: What's at line 689 of `EditCart`?

Comment: LINE 689: }else if(spinnerOpt2.equals(sel_opt2)){

Comment: Yes, so your `Adapter` is `null`. I can't see enough of your code but maybe you are initializing them after you call this task. Either way, it is `null` when you call `.equals()` on it

Comment: I added where I load my spinner. After the Adapter is loaded, I grab the User Selection from my DB and set the position of the spinner to that value. But I am not sure how to check that the value still exists a week from now if they log in and the cart is repopulated. All I need to do is verify that the Selection exists before setting the position.

Comment: Then you need to get your list from the DB and see if your `Spinner` selection is contained in that list still or not. Not compare your adapter to the values in your DB.

Comment: That is correct. I had done this earlier and it wouldn't work. What I am doing now is Checking the value agains the list that populates the adapter. It works fine.

Comment: It was simple. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the Value "RED" against the List that populates the Adapter. Code is posted above.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I see the problem. Your `ArrayAdapter`s are `null`. You never initialize them

```
ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerOpt1;
 ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerOpt2;
 ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerOpt3;
```

you need to initialize these somewhere beore using them in `onPostExecute()`

This is assuming line 689 is `else if(spinnerOpt1.equals(sel_opt1))`, from what I see. If not then you may have other problems, also, but those need to be initialized

Comment: I do initialize them. They populate the spinners in another class in this activity.

Comment: There is no issue populating the spinners. What I am trying to do is verify that "Spinner1" contains Selection "RED" before setting the position to "RED".

Comment: I see, it looked like you were declaring them in the `AsyncTask`. What is at line 689? Something is `null`